# How to embed a Google Spreadsheet inside a post in my blog?

Tags: google-sheets, embed, wordpress.com

I have a public Google Spreadsheet in Google Drive and want to display it within my blog post (people can directly see it, not only a link to the sheet).

How can I do that? Please help!

I'm using blog from wordpress.com

Answer (score 7):

From [Google Docs Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/37579?hl=en&ref_topic=2818999):

> **Publishing**
>
> Once you're done creating and editing your spreadsheet, you can publish it to a webpage. >Just click the **Share** drop-down menu on the top right and choose **Publish as a webpage**. Then, click **Publish now**.
>
> Then, everyone you choose can access your spreadsheet by entering the URL you send them into their browser's address bar.
>
> *`Even after you publish a spreadsheet, it won't appear in any search index.`*
>
> **Embedding**
>
> After you publish your spreadsheet, you can share it with the world by embedding it (or parts of it) in a website or blog.
>
> Publish your spreadsheet following the steps listed above and a unique URL is generated.
> Use this URL to embed the spreadsheet on your website or blog.
> You can also insert a spreadsheet in Google Sites. Just click **Edit page** > **Insert** > **Spreadsheet** from within your site. You'll need to enter the URL of your spreadsheet to embed it.

Answer (score 4):

You don't say what blogging software you're using.

But if it's Blogger, as well as publishing the spreadsheet (as per the previous answer), you also need to use a [Web Element](http://www.google.com/webelements/) to display it in the blog.

NB: I haven't done this for a while, and when I last did the Google Docs publish command didn't have a "share to blogger " option.  There's a chance it's changed since (as it has for some other types of Google Docs)

Comment: Using http://www.google.com/webelements/docs/spreadsheets/# seems to be what I need. However when I tried, my published spreadsheet cannot be showed in my wordpress.com blog.

Answer (score 0):

UNTESTED

Detailed description at [How to Embed Google Sheets in WordPress](https://pressshack.com/embedpress/docs/embed-google-sheets-wordpress/) from which the steps in outline are:

> Step #1 Install The PublishPress Embeds Plugin
>   Step #2 Get URL Of Your Google Sheet
>   Step #3 Publish Google Sheet Embed On Your WordPress Site
>   Step #4 Edit Your Google Sheet Embed